# Ajax script not functioning correctly after server change

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a website which runs a star rating ajax script, from the follow source.

http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/rating-stars-script-ajax-php_s2

I have changed hosting for the website from a shared platform to a dedicated server which I control with Plesk. Since the change, the rating script has stopped working. All other aspects of the site are functioning correctly.

The following error is logged in the browser console.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at
>   XMLHttpRequest.cerere_http.onreadystatechange (ratings.js:12)

Does XMLHttpRequest have to be enabled before this will work?

Can anyone offer advice as to why this may have happened?

Comment: Isn't the given link is down and no one can see your code or issue

Comment: The coursesweb.net link? I can access it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The update to the server meant that the database connection now uses

> localhost:3306

The rating script uses a PDO connection which requires that the hostname and PDO be separated.